# How to use parsec to get sub-strings of specific pattern in a string

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I'm a newbie to Haskell, and now I'm learning to use parsec. I get stuck in one problem, that is, I want to get all the sub-strings which satisfies some specific pattern in a string. For example, from the following string,

> "I want to choose F12 or F 12 from F1(a), F2a, F5-A, F34-5 and so on,
>   but F alone should not be chosen, that is, choose those which start with F
>   followed by a digit (before the digit there could be zero or more than one space) and then by any character from ['a'..'z'] ++
>   ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9'] ++ ['(',')',"-"]."

the result should be [F12, F12, F1(a), F2a, F5-A, F34-5], where the space between the F and the digit should be deleted.

With the parsec, I have succeeded in getting one sub-string, such as F12, F2a. The code is as follows:

```
hao :: Parser Char
hao = oneOf "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ()-"
tuhao :: Parser String
tuhao = do { c <- char 'F'
           ; many space
           ; c1 <- digit
           ; cs <- many hao
           ; return (c:c1:cs)
           }
parse tuhao "" str -- can parse the str and get one sub-string.
```

However, I am stuck at how to parse the example string above and get all the sub-strings of the specific pattern. I have an idea that if F is found, then begin parsing, else skip parsing or if parsing fails then skip parsing. But I don't know how to implement the plan. I have another idea that uses `State` to record the remaining string that is not parsed, and use recursion, but still fail to carry it out.

So I appreciate any tip! ^_^

Comment: What's your input string? I'd like to take a look at this but though you give your expected output (`["F12", "F12", "F1(a)", "F2a", "F5-A", "F34-5"]`) but not the input

Comment: @AdamSmith apparently the problem statement itself is the input: "I want to choose **F12** or **F 12** from **F1(a)**…"

Comment: @AdamSmith As Zeta said, the problem description is the input.

Comment: With `[m| m<- subsequences "F1(a)F2aF5-AF34-5", elem m ["F12","F 12"]]` I got one ["F12"] and that is probably right. `subsequence` sequences by character so meaningless characters can be removes. I took out only space and comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `F12`, `F 12`, `F1(a)`, `F2a`, `F5-A`, `F34-5`

This is an incomplete description, so I'll make some guesses.

1. I would start by defining a type that can contain the logical parts of these expressions. E.g.

   ```
   newtype F = F (Int, Maybe String) deriving Show
   ```

   That is, "F" followed by a number and an optional part that is either letters, parenthesised letters, or a dash followed by letters/digits. Since the number after "F" can have multiple digits, I assume that the optional letters/digits may be multiple, too.

   Since the examples are limited, I assume that the following aren't valid: `F1a(b)`, `F1(a)b`, `F1a-5`, `F1(a)-A`, `F1a(a)-5`, `F1a1`, `F1-(a)`, etc. and that the following are valid: `F1A`, `F1abc`, `F1(abc)`, `F1-abc`, `F1-a1b2`. This is probably not true. [1]
2. I would then proceed to write parsers for each of these sub-parts and compose them:

   ```
   module Main where

   import Text.Parsec
   import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

   symbol :: String -> Parser String
   symbol s = string s <* spaces

   parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
   parens = between (string "(") (string ")")

   digits :: Parser Int
   digits = read <$> many1 digit

   parseF :: Parser F
   parseF = curry F <$> firstPart <*> secondPart
     where
       firstPart :: Parser Int
       firstPart = symbol "F" >> digits

       secondPart :: Parser (Maybe String)
       secondPart = optionMaybe $ choice
         [ many1 letter
         , parens (many1 letter)
         , string "-" >> many1 alphaNum
         ]
   ```
3. *(As Jon Purdy writes in a comment,)* using this parser on a string to get multiple matches,

   ```
   extract :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
   extract p = do (:) <$> try p <*> extract p
           <|> do anyChar >> extract p
           <|> do eof >> return []

   readFs :: String -> Either ParseError [F]
   readFs s = parse (extract parseF) "" s

   main :: IO ()
   main = print (readFs "F12, F 12, F1(a), F2a, F5-A, F34-5")
   ```

   This prints:

   ```
   Right [F (12,Nothing),F (12,Nothing),F (1,Just "a"),F (2,Just "a"),F (5,Just "A"),F (34,Just "5")]
   ```

Takeaways:

- You can parse optional whitespace using token parsing (`symbol`).
- You can parse optional parts with [`option`, `optionMaybe` or `optional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:option).
- You can alternate between combinators using `a <|> b <|> c` or `choice [a, b, c]`.
- When alternating between choices, make sure they don't have overlapping FIRST sets. Otherwise you need to [`try`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:try); this is nasty but sometimes unavoidable. (In  this case, FIRST sets for the three choices are `letter`, `string "("` and `string "-"`, i.e. not overlapping.)

[1]: For the sake of restriction, I kept to the assumptions above, but I felt that I could also have assumed that `F1a-B`, `F1(a)-5` and `F1(a)-5A` are valid, in which case I might change the model to:

```
newtype F = F (Int, Maybe String, Maybe String)
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the main question of how to extract all of these from the input. You could do that with something like `catMaybes <$> many (try (Just <$> parseF) <|> (Nothing <$ anyChar))` (untested)

Comment: @JonPurdy: Thanks; that does make the parser a lot more useful.

Comment: @SimonShine & Jon Purdy Thank both of you! The suggestions are really helpful for me, esp. the usage of `many` and `try`, and it is the key to handle the unwanted character with `<$`, with which I can solve my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can get sub-strings of specific pattern in a string with the
[`findAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:findAll)
combinator from
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/).

Notice that this `tuhao` parser doesn't actually return anything. The `findAll` combinator just checks for success of the parser to find sub-strings which match the pattern.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either

let tuhao :: Parsec Void String ()
    tuhao = do
        void $ single 'F'
        void $ space
        void $ digitChar
        void $ many $ oneOf "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ()-"

input = "I want to choose F12 or F 12 from F1(a), F2a, F5-A, F34-5 and so on, but F alone should not be chosen, that is, choose those which start with F followed by a digit (before the digit there could be zero or more than one space) and then by any character from ['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0'..'9'] ++ ['(',')',\"-\"]."

rights $ fromJust $ parseMaybe (findAll tuhao) input
```

```hs
["F12","F 12","F1(a)","F2a","F5-A","F34-5"]
```